# For anidados para un list of dictionaries

Tags: python, bucle-for

Alguien me podria ayudar a como agregar la talla x-small a la lista mediante for anidados, no he podido, quiero que agregue el valor x-small a la key size de los objetos faltantes y si ya esta no agregar
tiene que ser con for anidado

```
products = [
    {'itemid': '1001', 'name': 'tshirt', 'colour': 'white', 'size': ['small', 'medium', 'large', '2x-large']},
    {'itemid': '1002', 'name': 'sweatshirt', 'colour': 'black', 'size': ['medium', 'large', 'x-large']},
    {'itemid': '1003', 'name': 'hoody', 'colour': 'green', 'size': ['x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large']},
    {'itemid': '1004', 'name': 'cap', 'colour': 'red', 'size': ['small', 'medium', 'large']}
]
list = []

for prod in products:
    for in list:
        if 'x-small' in prod:
            products[2]['size'] += ['x-small']
            list.append(prod)
            break
        else:
         if 'x-small' not in prod:
            products[2]['size'] += ['x-small']
            list.append(list)

print(list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

No necesitas `for` anidados, al recorrer los productos puedes acceder directamente a `size` y revisar si contiene `x-small` o no.

**Nota:** `list` es un nombre reservado en `python` por lo que crear una variable con ese nombre hará que el nombre reservado pierda su función.

Ejemplo completo:

```
products = [
    {'itemid': '1001', 'name': 'tshirt', 'colour': 'white', 'size': ['small', 'medium', 'large', '2x-large']},
    {'itemid': '1002', 'name': 'sweatshirt', 'colour': 'black', 'size': ['medium', 'large', 'x-large']},
    {'itemid': '1003', 'name': 'hoody', 'colour': 'green', 'size': ['x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large']},
    {'itemid': '1004', 'name': 'cap', 'colour': 'red', 'size': ['small', 'medium', 'large']}
]

# Recorrer los productos
for product in products:
    # Revisar si size contiene x-small
    # Podemos acceder directamente a la sublista size
    if 'x-small' not in product['size']:
        # Agrega x-small en caso de que no lo contenga
        product['size'].append('x-small')

print(products)
```

Esto devuelve lo siguiente:

```
[{'itemid': '1001', 'name': 'tshirt', 'colour': 'white', 'size': ['small', 'medium', 'large', '2x-large', 'x-small']},
{'itemid': '1002', 'name': 'sweatshirt', 'colour': 'black', 'size': ['medium', 'large', 'x-large', 'x-small']},
{'itemid': '1003', 'name': 'hoody', 'colour': 'green', 'size': ['x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large']},
{'itemid': '1004', 'name': 'cap', 'colour': 'red', 'size': ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-small']}]
```